# Why are tables created with default schema dbo although I specified a different schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

If I run a sql script in SQL Server 2005 SSMS (Version 9.00.4035.00) like

```
CREATE TABLE xxx.MyTable
```

the table will be created as dbo.MyTable although the schema xxx does exist! No error message!

The user I'm using to run the script as all permissions (tested with windows user and sql user with server role sysadmin)

What's wrong?

Comment: What do you get if you run `select SCHEMA_ID('dbo'),SCHEMA_ID('xxx')`? Does it give 2 different numbers, the same number, a null for one or both?

Comment: it gives different numbers. the xxx schema is totally ok. I can even create a dbo table and then change it to xxx. But I cannot create it directly!

Comment: another thing I've discovered. When the dbo.MyTable was created (instead of the desired xxx.MyTable) - and I try the same again, I get the error message that xxx.MyTable cannot be created as it already exists - although I cannot see it!!!

Answer (score 1):

You probably have 2 tables now

- xxx.MyTable
- dbo.MyTable

To check:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id), name, create_date, modify_date
FROM sys.objects
WHERE name = 'MyTable'
```

Don't rely on SSMS Object Explorer: it needs refreshed (right click on the tables node, refresh).

Or wrong database, wrong server etc.

We use schemas and *never* had any problems

Edit: now check all databases

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb '
    USE ?
    SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id), name, create_date, modify_date
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE name = ''MyTable''
'
```

Comment: No, I've definitely only the wrong xxx.MyTable (checked with your select statement).

Comment: @räph: "Or wrong database, wrong server etc.". CREATE TABLE xxx.myTable will create a table in the xxx schema: no ifs, no buts, it *will*

Comment: wrong server or wrong db cannot be - because the table is created and I can see it in the correct db - but smiply with the wrong schema!!

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at the possible workarounds:

1) Create a SQL login with dbo rights to the database where tables and other objects have to be created. Have the users connect to SSMS using the SQL login that you have created. Tables can be created using SSMS without issues.

2) Have the user of windows security group create table using TSQL. You will see that a new schema and user will be created for this database with the user name of the user. Table gets created with windows user name as the owner . 
Now, go to the database user which got created. Change the default schema to xxx.
User of that security group can create tables in SSMS and with dbo as the object owner.

Apparently, this is a microsoft bug and has not been resolved yet.

https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/viewfeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=238246&wa=wsignin1.0&siteid=68

Hope this helps.

Comment: At first I've used a Windows user. Now I've tested with a new SQL user and server role 'sysadmin' - which actually should have all rights to do anything?! But still not possible to create with the given schema!

Comment: This is unrelated to the question. That article is about "no default schema for windows principals". The question is "why did my table end up in dbo schema"